# log out clears Remember_me Cookie in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, remember-me

I am trying to enable "remember_me" functionality in grails. I am using latest version of Spring-security plugin for grails. 
I have tried many scenarios but the Remember_me functionality does not work. I can confirm that the cookie is created properly but it is deleted every time I logout and I guess that is the main reason that the functionality does not work.
This is the config that I have in my resource.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.alwaysRemember = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.key = 'admin'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.cookieName = 'grails_remember_me'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.tokenValiditySeconds = 360000

grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = [
        'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider',  'daoAuthenticationProvider']

grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.handlerNames =
        ['rememberMeServices',
         'securityContextLogoutHandler']
```

Anyone has a solution on my problem? Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: Isn't log out supposed to clear that?  I believe that the remember me capability is intended for use after session timeout, but not an explicit logout.

Answer (score 1):

> In "Remember Me" functionality, after a user login, user will have access from same machine to all its data even after session expired. This access will be possible **until user does a logout**.

Just add `<input name="_spring_security_remember_me" type="hidden" value="true"/>` to your login form.

Please check [this](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/latest/#rememberMeCookie) documentation for more details

Comment: I am using the default forms ... I do not have any gsp to modify .... grails and spring security handle all the gsp s and login related stuff...  when I inspect the form , the hidden input is there...

Comment: It sounds like your 'remember me' is working as intended.  Wait for a session timeout (set low for testing), then return to your application.  (Do not log out.)  Confirm that you do not have to log back in.